# Multiple npm install fails (EPERM error)

Tags: windows, node.js, npm, child-process

Im trying to install multiple packages in different child processes. And all the packages have some common dependency(browserify in my case).

```
example
|
|_pkg1
|   |_browserify
|
|_pkg2
|   |_browserify
|
|_pkg3
|   |_browserify
|
|_run.js
```

run.js:

```
var packages = ['pkg1', 'pkg2', 'pkg3'];

packages.forEach(function(pkg){
    exec('npm install ./' + pkg);
});
```

And `node run.js` fails with log

```
    npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
    npm ERR! argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i
    nstall" "./pkg3"
    npm ERR! node v0.12.2
    npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
    npm ERR! path C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\acorn\0.9.0\package\package.json
    npm ERR! code EPERM
    npm ERR! errno -4048

    npm ERR! Error: EPERM, rename 'C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\acorn\0.9.0\package\package.json'
    npm ERR!     at Error (native)
    npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, rename 'C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\acorn\0.9.0\package\package.json']
    npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
    npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
    npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Artem\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\acorn\\0.9.0\\package\\package.json',
    npm ERR!   parent: 'syntax-error' }
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Example: https://github.com/SakerONE/multiple-npm-install

Comment: The last error line holds the answer

Comment: @Roecrew, it didn't help, though

Comment: try to upgrade npm to latest version `npm install npm@latest -g`

Comment: Well, none of the solutions proposed worked for me, but found another one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51092497/1001395

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine with npm 2.9.1

Just try to upgrade your npm

`npm install npm@latest -g`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a tricky bug in npm, most probably, a race condition of parallel tasks writing the same package.json.

You can use `--force` flag to avoid cache (but it might be slow to download all dependencies on each build). Or wait for npm team to implement a permanent fix.

Related links to watch on Github:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues/323

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2500

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9696

Comment: Just rerunning the install command enough times also appears to "avoid" the race condition, sometimes. Many posts suggest disabling AV but for some that's not an option... --force flag may be a good idea in those cases