# Can't install package with npm install, EPERM error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I got an error when I try to install any package with npm install.

Here is an example when I try to install chart.js

> H:\testNG>npm install chart.js --save npm ERR! path
>   H:\testNG\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws-sign2\package.json
>   npm ERR! code EPERM npm ERR! errno -4048 npm ERR! syscall unlink npm
>   ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'H:\testNG\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws-sign2\package.json'
>   npm ERR!     at Error (native) npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not
>   permitted, unlink
>   'H:\testNG\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws-sign2\package.json'
>   npm ERR!     at Error (native) npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM:
>   operation not permitted, unlink
>   \'H:\testNG\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws-sign2\package.json\'\n
>   at Error (native)', npm ERR!   errno: -4048, npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
>   npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink', npm ERR!   path:
>   'H:\testNG\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws-sign2\package.json'
>   } npm ERR! npm ERR! Please try running this command again as
>   root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\flaur\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-09-04T16_16_04_331Z-debug.log

I will provide the log file if someone want to watch it
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgNenwMMyZRWg4tRDcK4OeoiZKeVZw

Comment: And..I don't have any permission set on the file, just "ng new .." and "npm install chart.js --save".

Comment: No antivirus, just Windows Defender

Comment: The following worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/51092497/1001395 (Spoiler, is not the Antivirus, is Windows Indexer!)

Answer (score -1):

i was occur same thing. now, i solved. that's so simply
npm 4.0 was not apply.. some node_modules packages. 
so you re install npm3.0

Comment: I don't understand. My npm version is 5.4.0

Comment: oh. my answer was reinstall Your npm  version 5.3.0.